# How to know when a provider has been completed after applying in Terraform

Tags: go, terraform

Is there a hook or API in the providers API for custom Terraform providers to know when all the resource mutations have been completed? I'd like to call an additional endpoint of the service to signal completion.

Comment: You could theoretically add an extra resource to your provider that is last in the dependency chain either directly by feeding in outputs of other resources in a way that makes sense or by having the user use `depends_on` to trigger it last. Do you have a slightly less theoretical or more worked example?

Comment: What do you mean by `a provider has been completed`? The applying is successful?

Comment: If you're writing your own terraform provider, you may be able to call the `Hook` for post-apply here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/master/terraform/hook.go

Answer (score 0):

In the Terraform model, each operation in the plan is expected to be a complete and standalone action that leaves the system in a consistent state where the externally-visible side effects have occurred and no other transient state is present. This design is particularly important for configurations that blend resources from several different providers together, where the other provider could depend on an intermediate result being externally-visible already, such as:

- Create a thing X in system A using provider A
- Create a thing Y in system B that depends on thing X using provider B
- Create a thing Z in system A that depends on thing Y using provider A

For many target systems, this comes "for free" as a natural side-effect of REST-like API design: the mutation operations themselves are designed to transition the system between consistent states, and the new state is visible immediately after the operation is completed. (with some caveats about eventual consistency, etc)

This model is trickier for systems that have a more complex lifecycle, such as expecting a batch of changes to be made before "committing" them to make their side-effects visible. The usual way to model these in Terraform is to make each separate change delimit itself, rather than try to delimit the overall set of changes.

In other words, each separate action should itself be considered its own "transaction", which should be fully applied and all of its transient state ended before the provider returns.

In some *particularly* tricky systems it can be necessary to serialize these "transactions" because only one can be open at a time. In that case, a provider can use a normal Go mutex to ensure that only one operation from that provider can run at a time. This will decrease Terraform's ability to run actions concurrently, but that is unavoidable if the remote system requires serialization of actions.

Note also that users can write more than one configuration for the same provider using [alternate provider configurations](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances), and in that case your provider plugin would be started up multiple times at once with no built-in ability to coordinate actions between them. In that case, the actions for one provider instance *will* run concurrently with actions for another, because these instances are entirely separate from one another (a separate OS process running the same program).